# Quarkus App Failed to start application in dev mode: Multiple Exceptions were thrown

Tags: quarkus

Need help with a Quarkus Application not starting. I am using Quarkus 2.16.7 and maven 3.9.2. Java 11. I am running the build on a mac. There are multiple exceptions being reported:

1. Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider
2. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.TypeArg
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpBinderConfiguration was not found

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
2023-06-09 23:17:38,645 ERROR [io.net.res.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders] (build-82) Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS. Check whether you have a dependency on 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos'. Use DEBUG level to see the full stack: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
2023-06-09 23:17:38,976 DEBUG [org.hib.val.int.uti.Version] (Quarkus Main Thread) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.5.Final
2023-06-09 23:17:39,126 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.TypeArg
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:516)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:466)
at io.vertx.mutiny.ext.web.Router.(Router.java:30)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.createMutinyRouter(VertxHttpRecorder.java:292)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$preinitializeRouter1141331088.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$preinitializeRouter1141331088.deploy(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:108)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-06-09 23:17:39,126 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.TypeArg
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:516)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:466)
at io.vertx.mutiny.ext.web.Router.(Router.java:30)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.createMutinyRouter(VertxHttpRecorder.java:292)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$preinitializeRouter1141331088.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$preinitializeRouter1141331088.deploy(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:108)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-06-09 23:17:39,126 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2023-06-09 23:17:39,126 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
2023-06-09 23:17:39,197 WARN  [io.net.uti.con.DefaultPromise] (vert.x-acceptor-thread-0) An exception was thrown by io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase$$Lambda$1242/0x0000000800788c40.operationComplete(): java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpBinderConfiguration was not found
at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.VertxMeterBinderAdapter.createHttpServerMetrics(VertxMeterBinderAdapter.java:63)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.createMetrics(HttpServerImpl.java:71)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase.lambda$null$1(TCPServerBase.java:184)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:97)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.AsyncResolveConnectHelper.lambda$null$1(AsyncResolveConnectHelper.java:61)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:578)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasksFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:426)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:375)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2023-06-09 23:17:39,197 WARN  [io.net.uti.con.DefaultPromise] (vert.x-acceptor-thread-0) An exception was thrown by io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase$$Lambda$1242/0x0000000800788c40.operationComplete(): java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpBinderConfiguration was not found
at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.binder.vertx.VertxMeterBinderAdapter.createHttpServerMetrics(VertxMeterBinderAdapter.java:63)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.createMetrics(HttpServerImpl.java:71)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.TCPServerBase.lambda$null$1(TCPServerBase.java:184)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:97)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.AsyncResolveConnectHelper.lambda$null$1(AsyncResolveConnectHelper.java:61)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:990)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:578)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasksFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:426)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:375)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:557)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: Please format the stack trace as it is close to impossible to read. 

One suggestion I have (that could very well be unrelated) is to try Maven 3.8.x as Maven 3.9.x only works in Quarkus 3+